# Wordpress Mega Menu remove Hover

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like assistance in removing the hover effect from dead links in my Wordpress Mega Menu, heres the link to the website: http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/

For example, in the first menu under "print and document division" , the dead link is "Software and Integration"

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which ones are "dead links". Please give us some code or explain further

Comment: also - you shouldn't just give us a website link and say "fix this" :) We're here to help - no clue which you mean with "Dead links"

Comment: For example, in the first menu under "print and document division"  , the dead link is "Software and Integration" ... my apologies for the vague question, I am new to Stack Overflow

Comment: So ive tried using something like:                                                   
a.mega-menu-link{
background-color: transparent !important;
text-decoration: none !important;

}

Answer (score 0):

you have !importants in your custom css - so it is hard to overwrite - 
If you get rid of that, you can target it with css.

Here i am using important, but i would suggest to remove it when you get rid of the importants in your custom.css near line 873

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item-has-children.mega-disable-link > a.mega-menu-link:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

But this seemed to work with what you were asking.

Comment: always better to add css hierarchy instead of !importants ;)

Comment: Yeah so I have tried out your code and the hover effect is removed on all links, not just the dead links. I removed !important from line 873 but still no luck

Comment: Wow seems like I can learn a lot from Stack Overflow and receive solid advise!

Comment: I missed a thing - 2 secs

Comment: Cool, i am trying everything but nothing seems to work to remove the hover.

Comment: using this code - I don't have it on the dead links anymore - but still have it on the submenues.

Comment: I am seeing a black hover effect on all links now, does not seem to have worked

Comment: Thats after using this code:                                                                                             ul#mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item-has-children.mega-disable-link a.mega-menu-link:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}

Comment: So you saw that i forgot the :hover :-D

Comment: on line 857, the > is missing - making it effect all of the links

Comment: ul#mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-item-has-children.mega-disable-link a.mega-menu-link:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}

Comment: just before the a tag :)  - #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item-has-children.mega-disable-link > a.mega-menu-link:hover

Comment: My Man!! Thank you so much Stender, it is now working :)

Comment: I hold upvotes and acceptances dear :) 
GL on future development and welcome to SO.